# merging two left join on same table into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to merge these 2 left join into one?

I can't think of any way

```
select  left1.field1,
        left2.field2
from masterTable left join (
    select somefield, 
         field1, 
         row_number() over (partition by somefield orderby otherfield) as rowNum
    from childTable 
    inner join masterTable 
        on masterTable.somefield = childTable.somefield
    ) as left1
        on masterTable.somefield = left1.somefield
                AND left1.rownum =1
left join (
    select  somefield,
            max(field2) as field2
    from childTable 
    inner join masterTable 
        on masterTable.somefield = childTable.somefield
    where field3 = 1
    group by somefield
    ) as left2
        on masterTable.somefield = left2.somefield
```

Comment: Hey! Did you check my answer? Just curious :)

Comment: @gofr1 i will take a look on Monday, so far the inline windowing function seem to do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `max() over()` to get the max of field2 per somefield in the same query.

```
select left1.field1,
       left1.field2
from masterTable 
left join
(select 
 somefield,field1 
,row_number() over (partition by somefield orderby otherfield) as rowNum
,max(field2) over(partition by somefield) as field2
from childTable 
inner join masterTable on masterTable.somefield = childTable.somefield) as left1
ON masterTable.somefield = left1.somefield 
AND left1.rownum =1 AND field3 = 1
```

Comment: interesting, going to test that pattern, back when i'm done, my real query is a little bit more complex than that small sample

Comment: i suggest you to try your query and mine and then comment.

Comment: working but you need to fix one thing, the AND field3 = 1 is screwing the result, i had to do ,max(case when field3 = 1 then sumfield2 else null end) over(partition by somefield) as field2, (make sense right?)

Comment: i am not sure what your result should look like. the modification you did may be needed for your scenario.

Comment: because the max() is based on a group by somefield and the filter (where clause) need to happen when evaluating it, not after the fact

Comment: otherwise max will be done on ALL row even the one that are not field3=1

Answer (score 0):

Please try this ..

```
select left1.field1,
       left1.field2
from masterTable 
left join
(select 
 somefield,field1 
,row_number() over (partition by somefield orderby otherfield) as rowNum
,max(field2) over(partition by somefield) as field2
from childTable 
inner join masterTable on masterTable.somefield = childTable.somefield
group by somefield,field1 
,row_number() over (partition by somefield orderby otherfield) 

) 
as left1
ON masterTable.somefield = left1.somefield 
AND left1.rownum =1 AND field3 = 1
```

Comment: this query won't work. you can't have a window function in `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but without samples of data and output I can't guarantee that it will work properly, it's just guessing.

```
SELECT  field1,
        MAX(field2) AS field2
FROM (
    SELECT  ct.field1,
            ct1.field2,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ct.somefield ORDER BY ct.otherfield) as rn
    FROM masterTable mt
    INNER JOIN childTable ct
        ON mt.somefield = ct.somefield
    LEFT JOIN childTable ct1
        ON mt.somefield = ct1.somefield AND ct1.field3 = 1
    ) as t 
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY ct.field1
```

Comment: it give me this error; windowed function can only appear in the select or order by clauses. so it seem it is an invalid query

Comment: Yeah! Forgot about ROW_NUMBER() in WHERE clause is not possible. I changed the answer :)